# Is there a way to do this effect with images on hover with css?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a div with 40px width and 40px height, inside i have an image (or background-image: url();) with a blue facebook icon (blue "f" without background). I wan't that when i hover that div, the logo on blue turns white and the background which is transparent turn blue, using just one image with just one logo in it. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have any HTML/CSS?

Comment: No, i mean, i know i can make that with two images or just with one with background position, but i want to make something like this:

`.image:hover{ background-color: blue;}`

or something like that

Comment: @nick to be able to change `f` from blue to white you must use two images.

Comment: ok, but if i use a sprite with background position, and i pt a transition property, the transition is a "slide" effect, how can i do a "fade" effect?

Comment: @nick you can get fade effect only with two images, I think...

Comment: How about putting a `<canvas>` on top of the image and then using JavaScript to manipulate the rgb-values of the image below to show the new "inverse" image?

Comment: i don't know how to use canvas :( anyway, i'll try this, thanks!

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/fade-effect-for-background-image-sprite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with text, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/ajULg/)**</kbd>

```
<div>f</div>
```

---

```
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma;
 font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #415e9b;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
div:hover {
  background: #415e9b;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: that's genius, but when the 'f' it's a logo, for example the twitter logo?

Comment: @nick that's the problem, in that case you must use two images or better image sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You did not ask for a solution using JavaScript. However, I tried using an HTML `<overlay>` with some JavaScript, and it seems to work just fine.

The overlay is positioned exactly above the image, and hidden at first. It is shown only while the mouse is inside the image.

The computation expects the background of the image to be transparent.

I hope it helps.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inverse Image on Hover</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #logoImage, #logoOverlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #logoOverlay {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <img id="logoImage" src="logo.png" width="40" height="40" alt="logo">
        <canvas id="logoOverlay" width="40" height="40"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
        var image = document.getElementById("logoImage");
        image.onmouseover = showOverlay;

        var overlayCanvas = document.getElementById("logoOverlay");
        overlayCanvas.onmouseout = hideOverlay;

        var overlayContext = overlayCanvas.getContext("2d");

        overlayContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, overlayCanvas.width, overlayCanvas.height);
        var overlayImageData = overlayContext.getImageData(0, 0, overlayCanvas.width, overlayCanvas.height);
        var length = overlayImageData.data.length / 4;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var r = overlayImageData.data[i * 4 + 0];
            var g = overlayImageData.data[i * 4 + 1];
            var b = overlayImageData.data[i * 4 + 2];
            var a = overlayImageData.data[i * 4 + 3];
            applyEffect(i, r, g, b, a, overlayImageData.data);
        }
        overlayContext.putImageData(overlayImageData, 0, 0);

    }

    function applyEffect(pos, r, g, b, a, data) {

        // your computation here based on red, green, blue, alpha pixel values
        if (a < 10) {
            // facebook blue
            data[pos * 4 + 0] = 59;
            data[pos * 4 + 1] = 89;
            data[pos * 4 + 2] = 152;
            data[pos * 4 + 3] = 255;
        }
        else {
            // opaque white
            data[pos * 4 + 0] = 255;
            data[pos * 4 + 1] = 255;
            data[pos * 4 + 2] = 255;
            data[pos * 4 + 3] = 255;
        }
    }

    function showOverlay()
    {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("logoOverlay");
        overlay.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    function hideOverlay()
    {
        var overlay = document.getElementById("logoOverlay");
        overlay.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```